# How can I install apps to 'Phone capacity'

Tags: applications, internal-storage, installation

I have a General Mobile Discovery 16GB, Android 4.2.1 -- Kernel 3.4.5

When I go to my storage settings, I have this screen.

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Now my apps are installed on system capacity part. Is there a way to make them installed on Phone Capacity?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->Apps, select a app and choose "Move to SDCARD", it should move it to Phone capacity, but if that doesn't work, root is the only solution I guess

Comment: That first part could work, but how root is the solution is incomprehensible here. Root is just a binary or user, isn't it? Please detail more.

Comment: You didn't mention, if you have root access or not, because if you have, you can just use a link

Comment: You mean OP (not me) didn't mention! What do you mean by *a link*?

Comment: You make a folder to Phone capacity, then you _link_ it to where apps go and now your phone thinks, that it saves stuff to where your apps should go, but instead they go to Phone capacity's folder

Comment: About rooting, I have no idea what is it. So I need to understand it appereantly.

Comment: @rebane2001 Also, couldn't find `Move to SD Card` option under apps. I click on an app, I got `Force Stop`, `Uninstall`, `Clear Data`, `Clear Cache` etc.. but no `Move to SD Card`

Comment: Then you can't do it unless you've got root